# File not found error for custom SharePoint 2010 pages in _Layouts

Tags: url, layout, sharepoint-2010, reference

I've created multiple custom application pages using VS 2010 and have deployed them to my SharePoint site.

I'm running into an issue when trying to reference these pages by a URL...

If I use http://myserver/sites/mysite/_layouts/MyApp/MyPage.aspx everything works perfectly, and I can view my pages.

If I use http://myserver/_layouts/MyApp/MyPage.aspx I get a HTTP 404 Not Found error.

Is there a way I can navigate to my custom page by URL without a specific site reference? Everything I've looked at says that I should be able to access this page directly from /_layouts but it doesn't seem to work.

Note: If I look at the folder "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MyApp" on my server, I see all the aspx pages...

Comment: Are you using a multi-server farm, or one server?

Comment: You may wish to ask similar questions on the SharePoint SE site: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried another browser? I only have this problem using Firefox, Internet Explorer works perfect. Tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the page works on one Site Collection but not the other, it seems to indicate a feature scope issue. However, I'm not sure how this would interfere with pages under `_layouts`.

Is your application page associated with a Site Collection level (or lower) scoped feature?

If so, is that feature activated on the root Site Collection (`http://myserver` in your example)? Activating the feature or expanding its scope may well resolve the problem.